# Autenticação do Facebook em um aplicativo utilizando o Azure

Tags: android, facebook, autenticação, microsoft-azure, filtro

Boa tarde, sou nova aqui e estou em um projeto para a criação de um aplicativo híbrido (Android e IOS), estamos no começo e não entendemos de programação Android - vamos aprender enquanto fazemos o projeto -, até agora definimos apenas que utilizaremos o Microsoft Azure.

Pensamos em inserir uma autenticação pelo Facebook como forma de Login, porém precisamos analisar uma informação pessoal (gênero) do usuário e, se ela for verdadeira, permitir o acesso. Ou seja, queremos possibilitar que apenas mulheres criem uma conta no aplicativo e para isso pensamos em, inicialmente, utilizar o Facebook.
É claro que isso não elimina a possibilidade de criação de contas fakes, mas a princípio seria uma solução razoável.

Assim, gostaria de saber se é possível realizar esse "filtro" utilizando informações do perfil do Facebook e se isso deve ser implementado logo no começou ou é melhor fazer a base do aplicativo primeiro.

Comment: É possível implementar esse filtro, nos tutoriais do próprio [facebook para desenvolvedores](https://developers.facebook.com) explica como obter dados do perfil de quem está se autenticando pelo app, e um desses dados é o género.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A documentação do [Facebook para Desenvolvedores](https://developers.facebook.com) é bastante completa para fazer o que você precisa.

Veja aqui tudo sobre [Login no Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login), desde para logar em aplicativos iOS e Android, quanto Websites e demais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É importante considerar que você apenas terá a informação de gênero do usuario após sua autenticação em sua aplicação. Então:

1. O usuário se loga na sua aplicação com o Facebook;
2. Sua aplicação permite ou não que ele navegue pelo app usando seu gênero como filtro.

Acredito que o gênero faça parte de informações básicas de login, porém vocês poderão customizar quais informações vocês precisam que sejam obrigatórias para conclusão do login. Recomendação: Quanto menos pedir de informação, melhor.